# How to add new Column in pyspark and insert multiple values with based on rows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark.
I want to add a new column with multiple values and the partition with those values.

```
import math

coun=df.count()

if(coun<= 20000):
    chunksize=2
    rowsperchunk = math.ceil(coun/2)
else:
    chunksize= math.ceil(coun/20000)
    rowsperchunk = 20000

for i in chunksize:
    df.limit(num_rows_per_chunk).withColumn('chunk',F.lit(i))
```

in for loop above it will only insert 1 value till limit

**example:** i have 100k rows in my data frame so chunk size will be 5.
and rows per chunk is 20 000
so i need add new column first 20 000 rows need to be inserted with value 1 and the next 20 000 rows needs to be inserted with value 2. till the end of chunksize. then i want to partition based on the new column we created

Comment: Have you found the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to repartition the data so that it is partitionned in partitions of the same size, and while preserving the order.

In it not that easy in spark. What I would do is start by counting the size of each partition. Then, for each partition I would compute the number of records that are in the dataframe in the previous partitions. With that and the rank of the record in the partition (`partition_rank`), a division by the size of the desired partitions will give me the new allocation. Note that I introduce an `index` column to compute the rank and preserve the order. Here is the code:

```py
partition_size = 20000

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
part_counts = df.withColumn("p", F.spark_partition_id()).groupBy("p").count().collect()
part_counts.sort()
part_counts = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in part_counts]

cum_part_counts = []
sum=0
for index, count in part_counts:
    cum_part_counts.append((index, sum))
    sum+=count
cum_part_counts_df = spark.createDataFrame(cum_part_counts, ['partition_index', 'count'])

repartitioned_df = df\
  .withColumn("partition_index", F.spark_partition_id())\
  .withColumn("index", F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
  .withColumn("partition_rank", F.rank().over(
           Window.partitionBy("partition_index").orderBy("index")))\
  .join(cum_part_counts_df, ['partition_index'])\
  .withColumn("new_partition",
      F.floor((F.col("count") + F.col("partition_rank") - 1)/partition_size))\
  .orderBy("index")\
  .write.partitionBy("new_partition").parquet("...")
```